# What would be the ideal composition of a newly founded society?

Tags: society, civilization, space-colonization

Imagine the following situation: There is a global catastrophe that will destroy the earth and there is a habitable planet in reach for spaceships. But it is technically possible to bring only 50,000 people to that planet who have to found a new society there.

What would theoretically be the ideal composition of these 50,000 people concerning sex, age, education, profession etc.? Are there any studies or statistics concerning this topic (ideal composition of a society, not inhabiting new planets)?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm sure there are some scientific reports about this topic already. I don't know any reference though.

Comment: Biologists, Medics .... to study viruses and bacteria on the new planet are a must.

Comment: Probably the most dangerous bacteria on the new planet would be the ones that they will carry with them.

Comment: I imagine this is largely dependent on the amount of infrastructure and automation they can bring with them. The less on both accounts, the more biased towards more mundane tasks the selection will become. Some roles, like the arts, will be entirely subjective. Others, like psychologists or economists, will be arguably subjective.

Comment: You want 0% of the population to be self-centered egomaniacs.

Comment: @EvilSnack u misunderstand their role in society, they are useful and you should have some. They are receptors, and can help detect processes inside society.

Answer (score 5):

A smaller society can be managed much better, without the need of full blown government, economy and the like. I believe occupations would be around like this: miners (1k), botanists (250), farmers (2k), medical doctors/ER personnel (1k), civil engineers (100), electrical engineers/technicians (1k), computer programmers/technicians (100), mechanical engineers/mechanics (1k), builders (1k), teachers (2k), factory workers (5k), caretakers (1k), cooks (500), law enforcement (1k), scientists of various fields (2k), entertainers (artists, musicians, etc) (250), managers (2k), children from all age groups (~30k). These numbers tilted a bit to ensure sufficient food production despite the alien world. Additionally, there should be enough builders to create a town in the middle of an alien planet.

All occupations should be at their ideal age. A very young engineer may not have the capability of an experienced one. Gender distribution should be 50%. All people on board should be sufficiently educated. But most importantly, everyone on board should be free of genetic defects and should be tested psychologically. You would ideally want people that will be able to cope with a task like this.

Comment: Note that the gender distribution is important only for breeding-age and younger people.  If the set-up includes people past that stage of their lives, the gender composition of that cohort should avoid extremes but is otherwise not important.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to skew the genders towards women? (ie. one man can get many women pregnant but a women can only birth 1 child (not including multiples) every 9 months or so). I imagine having children would be a pretty big priority.

Comment: 50k is a sizeable population, population boom is not the best idea when there is no guarantee that you will be fed or have roof on your top. Ideally, you should get males to heavy jobs and females to soft/replaceable jobs. It is not the best idea to do factory or building job while pregnant or nursing a child.

Answer (score 4):

This is really a philosophical question. What kinds of people form the seed of the society you want to live in?
Everyone will choose a different mix, everyone will feel there's is the best choice but there's probably no way to objectively compare two different answers without obvious flaws.

The outcome does not depend solely on the choice of people. Other important considerations are the equipment, technology and supplies you get to bring, as well as the conditions on the ground at the destination. I'm going to assume we can bring high technology and basically any equipment we wish and that the destination is largely earth-like (because anything else makes the people question pretty irrelevant)

I'm concerned with preservation of knowledge, science and technology. I'd try to bring every shred of knowledge ever generated in duplicate form, samples of all recorded genetic diversity. Redundant expertise with every field of science and technology. And a core of thinkers and artists that represent the best humanity has to offer.

I'd bring renowned professors in as many important fields as possible and use the transit time to spread the knowledge around more widely. Consider NASA's practice of choosing highly skilled astronauts with multiple advanced degrees.

I'd do loose screens of genetic and mental health (try not to tyrants about it, because nobody wants to live in a society like that)

Some additional important questions which will affect your outcomes:
How long does the trip take? What's the command structure on the ship? What's the proposed social structure at the destination?